# jquery to fetch ajax not POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fetch-api

I want to convert some jquery code to javascript code

This is a sample of original jquery

```
data.push({name: "value", value: "test"});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "src/routes.php",
    data:data,
    dataType: 'json',
})
```

routes.php have only this line

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and this is the response

```
Array
(
    [value] => test
)
```

This is javascript code

```
data.push({name: "value", value: "test"});

const request = new Request('src/routes.php', {
     headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }),
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
});

fetch(request).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
```

but the server replies this way

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Your original is sending form-urlencoded data in the body of the request. Your new version is sending JSON. Are you sure the server is configured to accept a JSON-formatted body?

Comment: Why are you converting to JSON? jQuery converts the object to a url-encoded string.

Comment: PHP can't process JSON into `$_POST` automatically.

Comment: change ```body: JSON.stringify(data)``` to ```body: data``` also not working... Must change headers content-type?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't json stringify your data that's all;

```
const request = new Request('src/routes.php', {
     headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }),
     method: 'POST',
     body: data,
});
```

Otherwise you have to read data from php://input

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: First block also not working... Must change content-type of headers?

Comment: Could you be more specific what is it not working?

Comment: As your first block, changing only ```body: JSON.stringify(data)``` to ```body: data``` also server didn't receive anything

Comment: could you check the request in network sectoin? Also could you share the picture of request?